# How do i convert a vector of values into a string of a certain format

Tags: r

Say my vector of values looks like this
`c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")`
I want to convert it into a string of the format below. Parenthesis at the beginning and end and single quotes for each element.
`"('AAA','BBB','CCC')"`
The length of the vector and the contents will be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Let a be your vector.

`paste0("('",paste0(a,collapse="','"),"')")`